# why does c skip a line of code when it has no reason to?

Tags: c

I have a linked list of struct PolyTerm where each term represents a term in the polynomial. The members are coeff(coefficient) expo(exponent) and struct PolyTerm *next which is the next term in the polynomial. Im creating a function to display the polynomial as a string. The following is my function. Size is the number of terms in my polynomial. The output i get at first is 3x0+-1x2+12x3+4x5. which is is what i want, except for the plus before the minus. to counter this I put an if(current->next->coeff >= 0) before adding the '+' into the array. But then i get an output as follows: 3x0-1x2+x3+4x5. Now, for the life of me I can't understand whats happening here. Can someone explain why 12 vanishes from the output.

```
           void displayPolynomial(){
            char *polynomial = (char *)malloc(4 *  size * sizeof(char));
            int i = 0;
            struct PolyTerm *current = head;
    
            if (polynomial == NULL){
            printf("Not enough memory\n");
            return;
            }
    
            while(current != NULL){
    
             snprintf(polynomial + i, sizeof(polynomial) - i, "%d", current->coeff);
             i += strlen(polynomial + i);
    
             polynomial[i] = 'x';
             i++;
    
             polynomial[i] = current->expo + '0';
             i++;
    
             if (current->next == NULL){
             break;
             }
    
    
             polynomial[i] = '+';
             i++;
             
    
    
             current = current->next;
    
             }
    
            polynomial[i] = '\0';
    
            printf("%s\n",polynomial);
            free(polynomial);
    }
```

I get an output of "3x0+-1x2+12x3+4x5" which is what I want, except for the plus sign before the negative sign.

```
if(current->next->coeff >= 0){
polynomial[i] = '+';
i++;
}
```

After this change the function prints 3x0-1x2+x3+4x5. I do not see any logical reason why 12 would not get added to the array.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates the symptoms which make you think that a code line is skipped.

Comment: I mean it's just one if statement that makes a line of code skip when there is no logical reason to, I really don't know how i can provide a better minimal reproducible example than that. I'm also displaying the change in output after adding the line of code.

Comment: Just a quick guess: 12 is greater or equal than 0, 12 gets replaced by "+". Hard to say without knowing what `current` contains.

Comment: People are guessing and pointing out things they would like to know for further analysis. Please reconsider providing a [mre], with hardcoded input data to demonstrate the symptoms which make you think that a line is skipped. You can also remove some blank lines and fix your indentation.

Comment: @BlueApricot a [mcve] is a piece of text that can be copy/pasted/compiled without any guesswork. Don't describe your code but show it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is causing undefined behavior:

```
         snprintf(polynomial + i, sizeof(polynomial) - i, "%d", current->coeff);
         i += strlen(polynomial + i);
```

`sizeof(polynomial)` will always evaluate to 4 or 8 depending on platform.  It's measuring the width of a pointer, not the width of the allocated string.  So once `i` goes above `8`, then `i -8` becomes...

That may not be your only bug.  The initial math equation being passed into `malloc` looks suspicious as well.  Given that a decimal integer can be as much 11 chars plus a null (12).

The easy solution... I think would be to avoid doing the `malloc` altogether and just "print as you go".

Your entire while loop can be simplified to just this:

```
while(current != NULL){
    printf("%dx%d%s", current->coeff, current->expo, current->next?"+":"");
    current = current->next;
}

printf("\n");
```

With the above, you don't need to invoke `malloc` or `free`. If you ultimately need to get the entire expression in a string, then do this:

```
size_t len = 0;
current = head;
while(current != NULL){
    char tmp[100];
    len += snprintf(tmp, 100, "%dx%d%s", current->coeff, current->expo, current->next?"+":"");
    current = current->next;
}

polynomial = (char*)malloc(len+1); // +1 for null char
polynomial[0] = '\0';
current = head;
while(current != NULL){
    char tmp[100];
    snprintf(tmp, 100, "%dx%d%s", current->coeff, current->expo, current->next?"+":"");
    strcat(polynomial, tmp);
    current = current->next;
}

printf("%s\n", polynomial);
free(polynomial);
```